# Windows Shortcut/Utility to switch between application windows

Tags: windows, windows-8, alt-tab

From using GNOME and MacOS, I'm accustomed to have <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to switch between windows of one application and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between applications.

I have not yet found any setting or utility which would yield the same functionality on Windows (8). Do you have any tips?

Comment: Whilst this is not inbuilt into Windows 8, this 3rd party utility maybe useful http://www.premeforwindows.com/ as it aims to speed up switching windows

Comment: An AutoHotkey script following [this algo](http://superuser.com/a/315881) would work.

Comment: See [Shortcut in Windows 7 to switch between same application's windows, like Cmd + ` in MacOS](https://superuser.com/q/435602/150988).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no built-in way to switch between the windows of the same application. All top-level windows are displayed in <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> list. I mean if you have two instances of Notepad running, you'll see two windows of Notepad in <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> window list.

If you activate two windows of the same application in row, you can switch between them with single <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> press.

Additionally you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to display the list of windows, and then use arrow keys to select the required window; press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to switch to the window.
You can also use mouse to select a window from this list.

---

As an alternative way you can use <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>: each press activates the next button on the Taskbar (including the pinned, not started, applications). When you reach the required application, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Up</kbd> and then use <kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Right</kbd> arrows to select the required window and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to switch to it.

Definitely <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> is slower than <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 24):

There actually is a way to do this and it's probably the most often-used keyboard shortcut in my arsenal.

Simply type <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>*number*</kbd>, where *number* is a single digit, 1, 2, 3, ..., 9, 0.  This allows you to access the first 10 applications that are currently sitting in your taskbar.
For example, I have Chrome pinned to the 1st location in my taskbar, so <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> always brings up Chrome.  My favorite text editor (Vim will never die!) is tied to <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>.  And on down the line.  I have the first 10 locations in my taskbar pinned so that I always know what a given <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>*number*</kbd> combination will bring up.

But more to the point, since the OP asked how to switch between multiple windows of the same application, here's where this keyboard shortcut gets really useful.  To refine what I said earlier, <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>*number*</kbd> brings up the *first instance* of the application.  But holding the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key brings up a list of windows of that application.  (Similar to when you mouse over the grouped icons of an application in the taskbar.)  Continuing to type <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>*number*</kbd> scrolls through that list.
For example, I earlier said I have Chrome tied to <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>.  More specifically, I always make sure that my gmail and calendar are in the first window of Chrome, so that <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> always jumps right to my email.  But if I want to cycle through any of my other Chrome windows, I just keep the <kbd>Windows</kbd> pressed down and keep typing <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>.

Another related and particularly useful variation of this is to add the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.  <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>*number*</kbd> brings up the last active window of the given application.  This is very useful when you keep toggling back and forth between two different windows of the same application.

***UPDATE Jan/2019***: *The above* <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>*number*</kbd> *shortcut appears to have been removed in Windows 10, starting from either version 1803 or 1809.  I'll update this answer if I figure out a way to re-enable this shortcut.  See https://superuser.com/a/1388225/288800, where there seems to be consensus that this is a bug, not a feature removal.  Hopefully that answer will contain useful information if I forget to come back and update this one.*

Please note that this answer was originally written when I was using Windows 7, but these shortcuts are also applicable according to Windows 8 and 10. 
 See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts for an explanation of the shortcuts in all three of those versions of Windows.  That link also explains <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> key variations which you may also find useful, so I recommend taking a look at it.

***UPDATE Nov/2019***: Microsoft appears to have restored the <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>*number*</kbd> shortcut in Windows 10 version 1903. Hooray!

Comment: Unfortunately, the Windows + number only works if applications are grouped in the taskbar (which they are by default.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This closes up the gap between win/mac usability a whole lot, although I still enjoy macOS' compact Cmd+` better.

Comment: Many thanks, this saves my day! I'm using PuTTY and right now installing 5 servers, where I have 2 windows for each. And when closing all of them (`Ctrl-D`) this is very smooth, and saves me at least 30 seconds per day :)

Comment: if we now get a "switch the current group"-shortcut, windows would be much better equipped than macOs

Answer (score 1):

Autohotkey solution works exactly like in MacOS - cycling windows inside one application:

```
!`:: ;
WinGetClass, CurrentActive, A
WinGet, Instances, Count, ahk_class %CurrentActive%
If Instances > 1
    WinSet, Bottom,, A
WinActivate, ahk_class %CurrentActive%
return
```

Replace !`(Alt+`) with #`(Win+`) if you want to use Win as a modifier key.
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#s21

Answer (score 0):

Alt-Tab switches between Applications in Desktop mode, Win-Tab switches between Metro apps. To my knowledge, there is no built-in way to have this consistent. There is also no way to switch between Windows of one application, unless the application provides that.

I hope I got your question right...

Comment: `Alt` + `Tab` includes Metro apps, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Autohotkey proves more useful to me in this regard. I simply cannot remember how I organize my applications each day. And I don't like them pinned to the taskbar (which gets resetted at times due to the company settings).

With AHK I have one button to switch between the current active application. And other dedicated buttons to switch to FireFox, Outlook, Excel and Notepad++. f1+F (or whatever shortcut you pick) is more memorable for me than windows+number to switch to Firefox.

Comment: Hi Gerard and welcome to Super User! Thank you for the suggestion to use AHK- can you share wither an example or a snippet of how you have achieved this in your script? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use dimaqw answer

you should use ahk_exe replace ahk_class, beacuse vscode and chrome name is same.

```
^Tab:: ;
; WinGetClass, CurrentActive, A
WinGet, CurrentActive, ProcessName, A
; MsgBox, The active window's class is "%CurrentActive%".
; WinGet, OutputVar, ProcessName, A
; MsgBox, The active window's class is "%OutputVar%".
WinGet, Instances, Count, ahk_exe %CurrentActive%
If Instances > 1
    WinSet, Bottom,, A
WinActivate, ahk_exe %CurrentActive%
return
```