# Where is the setting to allow me to automatically switch to a window with windows key + number?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, taskbar

I'm using Windows 10 on a new work laptop. From experience with my personal Windows 10 computer, I'm used to the keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Windows key</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) taking me to the N<sup>th</sup> application on the taskbar, counting from the left.

On my personal computer, if I have N running instances of an application pinned at e.g. position one on my taskbar, then when I press (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>) K times it will switch focus to the K<sup>th</sup> instance. That K<sup>th</sup> instance will then be active, and I can use it normally, without any other key presses needed.

On my work laptop, I can use this key combination, but I'm forced to press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in order to confirm that I want to open the K<sup>th</sup> instance. If I don't, Windows acts like a preview window, and the popup on the taskbar which shows *all* instances remains open. If I press anything other than <kbd>Enter</kbd> , Windows returns me to the app I am trying to navigate away from.

**I don't want to have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm my choice**. Quickly cycling through apps until I reach the right one is ingrained in my muscle memory. Having to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> means I keep typing into the wrong applications when Windows boots me out of the preview and back to whatever I was navigating away from. How can I change this behaviour?

Comment: Does this happen on the laptop when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: "switching between multiple running instances of the same application without needing to press enter. " Have you tried ALT+ TAB

Comment: If you read the question you would know I'm not referring to alt+tab. I'm talking about cycling through running instances of the same application, not cycling through all instances of all applications.

Comment: What is the Windows os build number on your work laptop?

Comment: And I hope you won't mind mentioning exactly what that confirmation dialog asks/say

Comment: There is no confirmation dialog. I never said there was one. Version 1903 (OS build 18362.592)

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing information from a similar question ([Windows Shortcut/Utility to switch between application windows](https://superuser.com/q/587971/455050)).

As @Robert stated the easiest way to switch between window of the same application would be to press <kbd>Windows key</kbd>+<kbd>number</kbd>, release then repress the number key to scroll through the open windows. Here is his example (from https://superuser.com/a/699846/455050).

> For example, I earlier said I have Chrome tied to <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>. More specifically, I always make sure that my gmail and calendar are in the first window of Chrome, so that Windows + 1 always jumps right to my email. But if I want to cycle through any of my other Chrome windows, I just keep the Windows pressed down and keep typing <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Windows key</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> starts (or switches to) the N<sup>th</sup> software **pinned** to your taskbar.

So if Chrome is pinned to your taskbar, and is in position 1, pressing Windows+1 starts/ switches to your Chrome instance. The position of the software on the taskbar indicates the number.

Comment: You haven't read the question. I'm talking about switching between multiple running instances of the same application without needing to press enter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of any way to change the functionality directly, apart from changing default behavior of the Windows key (which I'm assuming is not what you're looking for)

An alternative method is to use [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) (free scripting software) to map your (custom) functionality to the keypress.

An AutoHotkey script uses the keys on the left of the double colon `::` to 'Send' commands on the right of the colon. For example `<#` represents the Left Windows Key, and the Number `1` represents 1, so to map <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> would be:

```
<#1:: Send <#1{Enter}
```

The AutoHotkey docs are generally quite helpful, and a list of included keys is supported. There is an endless supply of template/example scripts online from simple things such as spellcheck all the way to automated actions in specific programs (Lightroom, etc). Moreover, there's a portable version which doesn't require Administrator Permission (I'm assuming there's a separate administrator account on your work laptop).

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm

However, for reference, the following can be used for your purpose (tested):

```
<#1:: Send <#1{Enter}
<#2:: Send <#2{Enter}
<#3:: Send <#3{Enter}
<#4:: Send <#4{Enter}
<#5:: Send <#5{Enter}
<#6:: Send <#6{Enter}
<#7:: Send <#7{Enter}
<#8:: Send <#8{Enter}
<#9:: Send <#9{Enter}
<#0:: Send <#0{Enter}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stupid as this sounds, have you updated your laptop? Check the version number of Win 10 on your computer, and see how it compares to you laptop, if you can maybe try to update it.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed the same issue but have found that altering how quickly I move between windows prevents it from happening.

If I press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and quickly release both before the previews of all the instances pop up, then I have to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to activate the currently selected window instance.  If I press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, then press and release <kbd>N</kbd>, and then wait to release the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key after the preview pops up, then it works as expected.  If you have your taskbar set to automatically hide, it is easier to recreate the issue because the taskbar has to unhide before the previews pop up.

I don't see this behavior on my work laptop (Windows 10 Version 1809) but it has been occurring on my home PCs for the last few (several?) versions.  My home PCs are Version 20H2.